# Binding to an explicitly implemented generic interface in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, generics, binding, interface, explicit-implementation

I understand it's possible to bind to an explictily implemented property using something like this:

```
"{Binding Path=(local:ISomeInterface.SomeProperty)}"
```

but what if the interface is generic?

```
"{Binding Path=(local:ISomeInterface&lt;TypeParama&gt;.SomeProperty)}"  ???
```

What is the magic syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the syntax for binding to a generic interface but, if you need a quick work around, you could simply encapsulate your property, i.e.:

```
public int SomePropertyYouCanBindTo
    {
    get
        {
        return (this as ISomeInterface<TypeParameter>).SomeProperty;
..... etc
```